# backup domain join on windows XP

Tags: windows-xp

I have a windows XP pro joined on a domain controller. Now I need to reinstall the entire O.S. but I don't want to go to the network administrator to ask to rejoin the machine to the domain.
Can I backup the current domain join informations and import its in the new installation?

Comment: Marco, I'm sorry I have to close this question, because it's off-topic for Serverfault. Btw, I'm pretty sure there is no simple way to "re-join" with a clean new installation. Just call your sysadmin, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

sounds like your doing something you shouldn't be doing!

You can try doing something like backing you your 'system state' with NTBackup & restoring that after you re-install, but that will bring with it the registry which is probably full of a lot of things you're trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to reinstall an OS and your not an administrator on your domain you need to contact the person who is an administrator on that network. Speaking for anyone who is a network administrator, nothing is worse then people doing things without you knowing when your responsible for how they function.